# How to get a discord bot in python to send a specific message in a channel after X time?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to be able to type !setreminder "Post this string later" 3 hours, and the bot will post this in a channel in 3 hours.

Would the below code work for this if I modified it? Or is there a better way to do this?

```
async def my_background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    counter = 0
    channel = discord.Object(id='channel_id_here')
    while not client.is_closed:
        counter += 1
        await client.send_message(channel, counter)
        await asyncio.sleep(60) # task runs every 60 second
```

If I ran this command, would I be able to use other commands at the same time while the bot was waiting to post?

Comment: Hello, I've noticed you haven't accepted any answers to the questions you've been asking since you've joined SO. You should consider choosing an answer that helped you and accepting it so others can see the solution.[Check out What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def setreminder(ctx,time:int,*arg:str):
  await asyncio.sleep(time)
  await client.say(f"\"{' '.join(arg)}\"")
```

Where you would run a `!setreminder 5 Hello World` (`5` being the amount of seconds you wish to wait for)

> If I ran this command, would I be able to use other commands at the same time while the bot was waiting to post?

Yes, you can use other commands because of the [nature of asyncio.sleep](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#sleeping)